# Angular2 value not selected in dropdown

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am unable yo figure out that what I am doing wrong actually I want to get value of dropdown to be selected in my form. I am using template driven form as :

```
 <select class="form-control" id="role"
                                        required
                                        [(ngModel)]="user.role" name="role"
                                        #role="ngModel">
                                <option *ngFor="let user_role of user_roles" [ngValue]="user_role">{{user_role.display_name}}</option>
                                </select>



 this.user = new User(user_details.name,user_details.email,user_details.roles[0],user_details.is_confirmed,'','',user_details.image);
```

**this is user_details.roles[0] :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "display": "Administrator",
    "pivot": {
      "user_id": 6,
      "role_id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

I am unable to figure out whats the issue why the value is not been selected. As per my investigation I am sure that this is due to "pivot" object inside [0] key but how i can handle this, I tried without "pivot" and it worked fine.

Comment: try removing `#role="ngModel"` this

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from my POV, I would use a Events for this case. Let me give you a classical and simple example and I hope that you can pick from this.

Assuming this is your HTML section.

```
<select (change)="newValue($event)" class="" name="">
   <option value="val1">1</option>
   <option value="val2">2</option>
   <option value="val3">3</option>
   <option value="val4">4</option>
</select>
```

and then, this is your typescript section.

```
newValue(event: any){
    let value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

You can then assign this value to your desired

```
this.user
```

object key attribute. I hope I have helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following changes.

```
<select class="form-control" id="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role" name="role" >
    <option [selected]="user.role == **CHECK_YOUR_NAME_CONDITION_HERE**" value="user_role" > {{user_role.display_name}} </option>
</select>
```